# Display age from DOB RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I am trying to output a users age using the dateofbirth stored in the database in 1984-12-28 format.

The dob is stored in the profiles

I have seen lots of answers but cannot work out where to put the code.

Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `age` method to your `User` model, which will substract `date_of_birth` from `Time.now()`. You can also format this so only full years would be returned (that's usual way to present age anyway). Later in your views just refer to this method.